# Show that $Z$ is Standard Normal iff $Z=^d-Z$

Tags: probability

Show that $Z$ is standard normal if and only if $Z=^d-Z$.  I know this seems like a simple question but for some reason I can't figure out the only if part.

For the if part, we use the fact that $Z$ is symmetric.  This means that $P(Z<z)=P(Z>-z)$. Then we have

$$P(-Z<z)=P(-Z>-z)=P(Z<z)$$

and hence $P(-Z<z)=P(Z<z)$.  However, for the reverse implication, I don't even know how to approach it.  I see that $Z=-Z$ in distribution would imply a symmetry around $0$, I just don't see how this statement is unique. What we know about this is that $P(Z<z)=P(-Z<z)$. Any insight into this is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What does $=^d$ mean?

Comment: Equal in distribution @lulu

Comment: If your hypothesis is that $Z$ and $-Z$ have the same distribution,  the conclusion that $Z$ is normally distributed is in general false.  If $Z$ is, for example, uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$, so is $-Z$, and it is not normal.

Comment: Well....what about the uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$ or, more simply, the variable $X=\pm 1$ with equal probability?

Comment: Alright that makes sense.  I figured there was an issue with the problem, it just didn't make sense.  Should've tried to come up with a counter example myself. Didn't really think this one through I guess.  Thank you to both of you

Comment: As regards to the formatting, `\stackrel{d}{=}` produces $\stackrel{d}{=}$.